# Active admin overwrite index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

For example I have two models:

1. User - has_many :posts
2. Post - belongs_to :user

I need column in index view where I can see Posts count of each user:

```
  index do
    column :id
    column :name
    column :created_at
    column "Posts count", :sortable => "posts.count" do |user|
      user.posts.count.to_s
    end
    default_actions
  end
```

My problem is :sortable => "posts.count" does not work, I received exception.

Comment: have you tried :sortable => false?

Comment: But I need sorting this column, how should I do this?

Comment: it will show you the post count associated with each user

Comment: he want to sort by this column!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find 4.1.2.4 paragraph on [the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). It's about `counter_cache`. I think that will help you. Just add in ActiveAdmin `column :posts_count`